# onItemCheckedStateChanged called twice

Tags: android, listview, android-actionmode

I'm having a weird issue and I am not sure what is going one precisely. I managed to bypass the problem by manually checking if the first item in the listview that got checked is the one that's getting the 2nd call.

The issue is that when the user long click on a listview item (onlongclicklistener inside of the adapter), the listview item gets checked. After the item is released (long click is released), the item gets set to isChecked=false. I cannot figure out what is causing this problem. If I understand correclty, setMultiChoiceModeListener has it's own onlongclick listener that gets called. Is there a way to override it and achieve the same funcionality like most of the apps (long click starts the selection procedure)?

**Adapter click listeners**

```
vi.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                Log.d("test abc", "ovo je krenulo");
                ((MainActivity) mContext).list.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
                ((MainActivity) mContext).lvPos = position;
                ((MainActivity) mContext).lvPosChecked = true;

                if(!((MainActivity) mContext).ListSelectionInProgress)
                {
                    ((MainActivity) mContext).ListSelectionInProgress = true;
                }

                if(!((MainActivity) mContext).list.isItemChecked(position))
                {
                    ((MainActivity) mContext).list.setItemChecked(position, true);
                }
                else
                {
                    ((MainActivity) mContext).list.setItemChecked(position, false);
                }
                return true;
            }
        });

        vi.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("CL", "State called");

                if(((MainActivity) mContext).ListSelectionInProgress)
                {
                    ((MainActivity) mContext).lvPos = position;
                    ((MainActivity) mContext).lvPos = -1;
                    if(!((MainActivity) mContext).list.isItemChecked(position))
                    {
                        ((MainActivity) mContext).list.setItemChecked(position, true);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                       ((MainActivity) mContext).list.setItemChecked(position, false);
                    }

                    Log.d("State", Integer.toString(((MainActivity) mContext).list.getCheckedItemCount()));
                }
            }

        });
```

**setMultiChoiceModeListener**

```
list.setMultiChoiceModeListener(new AbsListView.MultiChoiceModeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode mode, int position, long id, boolean checked) {
                if(position == lvPos && checked != lvPosChecked)
                {
                    list.setItemChecked(position, true);
                }
                mode.setTitle(Integer.toString(list.getCheckedItemCount()));
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu)
            {
                ListSelectionInProgress = true;
                MenuInflater inflater = mode.getMenuInflater();
                if(SUBLEVEL == 1) {
                    inflater.inflate(R.menu.action_mode_add, menu);
                }
                else if(SUBLEVEL == 5) // SATNICA
                {
                    inflater.inflate(R.menu.action_mode_remove, menu);
                }

                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {

                int c = 0;
                switch(item.getItemId())
                {
                    case R.id.selAll:
                        for(int i=0;i<list.getAdapter().getCount();i++) {
                            list.setItemChecked(i, true);
                        }
                        break;
                    case R.id.addSch:
                        c = 0;
                        for(int i=0;i<list.getAdapter().getCount();i++)
                        {
                            if(list.isItemChecked(i))
                            {
                                addToSchedule(i);
                                c++;
                            }
                        }
                        if(c > 1)
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, R.string.addToMyScheduleSuccessPlural, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, R.string.addToMyScheduleSuccess, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        mode.finish();
                        break;
                    case R.id.remSch:
                        c = 0;
                        if(list.getAdapter() != null)
                        {
                            for(int i=0;i<list.getAdapter().getCount();i++)
                            {
                                if(list.isItemChecked(i))
                                {
                                    removeFromSchedule(i);
                                    c++;
                                }
                            }
                            if(c > 1) {
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, R.string.removeFromMyScheduleSuccessPlural, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, R.string.removeFromMyScheduleSuccess, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                            loadMySchedule();
                            mode.finish();
                        }

                        break;
                }

                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
                ListSelectionInProgress = false;
            }
        });
```

**listview_item.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:id="@+id/classItemLV"
    android:background="@drawable/list_row"
    android:minHeight="80dp"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    android:elevation="2dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="16dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/lday"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:minWidth="16dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="P\nO\nN"
            android:id="@+id/DAY1"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/lTime"
        android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="false"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/lday">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="10"
            android:id="@+id/timeFrom"
            android:textColor="@color/colorLV3Dark"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textIsSelectable="false"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="12"
            android:id="@+id/timeTo"
            android:textColor="@color/colorLV3Dark"
            android:layout_below="@+id/timeFrom" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/lInfo"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/lTime">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Analiza financijskih izvještaja"
            android:id="@+id/className"
            android:textColor="@color/colorLV3Dark"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="prof. dr. sc. Ivan Ivić"
            android:id="@+id/classTutor"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:textColor="@color/colorLV3"
            android:layout_below="@+id/className" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="PREDAVANJE - DV41"
            android:id="@+id/classTypePlace"
            android:textIsSelectable="false"
            android:textColor="@color/colorLV3"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/classTutor" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="Datum: 5.10.-25.1."
            android:id="@+id/classDate"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorLV3"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/classTypePlace"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I have debugged the code as best as I could and I have noticed the following:

1) onItemCheckedStateChanged gets called after the long click is released

2) OnClick gets called normally and is not affected by the longclick listener at all (except enabling the selection trough a public boolean variable)

3) if I move my finger outside of the view, or to the other side of it, while holding down the touch event, it stays checked

4) if I quickly select a different item, both stay checked

It seems like something is overriding my listview item's checked state. What could it be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After two days of scratching my head, I finally managed to find a solution. I was handling my normal and long clicks inside of an adapter.

Seems like

```
setMultiChoiceModeListener
```

Handles both of those by itself and it was unnecessary to handle those two types of clicks manually. I wish I have read it somewhere sooner. I hope this answer will help someone in the future as well.